# How to update data in each loop rather that all loop data shown at once in Android

Tags: java, android

How would I in this code show each loops data separately rather than it working through the loop then displaying the data (I have tried using timers but didn't work).

```
int noStart = 20;
int minus = 5;
private void waitUntil(long time) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(time);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //This is just here to handle an error without crashing
    }
}
public void number(View view){
        for(int loop = 0;noStart<loop;loop+=5){
            noStart -= minus;
            TextView tx  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
            tx.setText(String.valueOf(noStart));
            waitUntil(500);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, you can use a `Handler` and also set a delay interval in milliseconds.

The code below executes 5 times every 0.5 seconds without blocking the UI thread.

```
final Handler h = new Handler();

h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    private int counter = 0;

    public void run() {

        // Update your text view here
        ...

        if (++counter < 5) {
            h.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use handler for this task. This way you main UI won't sleep.

```
Handler waitHandler = new Handler();
TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
waitHandler.post(waitRunnable);

int counter = 0;
static Runnable waitRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            tx.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tx.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                }
            });
        }
        counter+=5;
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
};
```

This would set the text on tx TextView with 2 second gap with 5,10,15,20 and 25.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about handlers